# Ext.view.View: Mouseenter and Mouseleave events on elements in an itemTpl

Tags: extjs4

I have a custom view, bound to a store, which renders an itemTpl for each record in the store.

In the itemTpl, there is a subtemplate that iterates over an array in the record to produce several divs.

I am attempting to attach an event handler to the mouseover/mouseout events for each of the subtemplate elements that are generated.  I am attempting to attach the eventhandlers in the afterrender event handler of the panel containing my view.  I can see that the afterrender event of the parent panel is run, and my code to attach the event handlers is also being run.

However, my handler never gets fired.  Any ideas?

itemTpl:

```
        this.itemTpl = ["<div>{label}</div>",
                    "<div class='ph_horz_carousel' id='ph_horz_carousel_{#}' style='display:none'>",
                        "<tpl for=\"subitems\">",
                            "<div class='ph_horz_item' id='horz_item_{#}' subitem_id='{#}'>",
                                "<img src='{inactive_img}' bsrc='{active_img}'/>",
                                "<span>{label}</span>",
                            "</div>",
                        "</tpl>",
                        "<div class='clear'></div>",
                   "</div>",
                   "<div class='clear'></div>"];
```

Sample record:

```
{
        label: 'Movies',
        subitems:[
            {
                label: 'super',
                active_img: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CD_autolev_crop.jpg/220px-CD_autolev_crop.jpg',
                inactive_img: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CD_autolev_crop.jpg/220px-CD_autolev_crop.jpg',
                launch_info: {
                    type: 'url',
                    target: ''
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Event handler:

```
Ext.query('.ph_horz_item', p).forEach(function(el){
                        var E = Ext.get(el);
                        E.removeAllListeners();
                        E.on({
                            mouseover: {
                                fn: function(){
                                    alert('it worked');
                                    debugger;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/KyRRa/)

In fact in `Ext.view.View`, you need to specify the [itemSelector](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View-cfg-itemSelector) of the View

> **[itemSelector](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View-cfg-itemSelector)**
>
> This is a required setting. A simple CSS selector (e.g. div.some-class or span:first-child) that will be used to determine what nodes this DataView will be working with. The itemSelector is used to map DOM nodes to records. As such, there should only be one root level element that matches the selector for each record.

So `View` will automatically hook events for you, and you can use any of their `itemmouse*` events.